# Displaying headers for each column displayed in multi column section layout in Crystal reports XI

Tags: crystal-reports, multiple-columns

I have a table with 2 types of values I want displayed in the report, let's call them Col1 and Col2.

If I choose multiple column layout of the Details section, that holds the data of that table, depending on the number of rows found for the table, I can have from 1 to 4 columns of data.

from something that fits in one column

```
Col1  Col2         
Val11 Val21 
Val21 Val22
```

to

```
 Col1  Col2    Col1    Col2     Col1   Col2    Col1      Col2
 Val11 Val21  Val1n+1 Val2n+1     .     .      Val13n+1  Val23n+1
  .      .      .        .        .     .    
  .      .      .        .        .     .    
  .      .      .        .        .     .    
Val1n Val2n  Val1n+n Val2n+n   Val13n Val23n
```

And, also, this section can be printed accros more than one page. I need Column headers (Col1 and Col2) displayed on each new page, and I need Column headers displayed only for columns that get printed out. So, the column header can be

`Col1 Col2`, or `Col1 Col2 Col1 Col2...` until `Col1 Col2 Col1 Col2 Col1 Col2 Col1 Col2,`depending on number of rows.

Any help highly appreciated!